Automatic Glossary Entries
I'm using LaTeX to create language teaching materials, and in particular, I am using the \marginpar command to create marginal notes explaining unfamiliar vocabulary items. My go-to custom command, which works exactly as intended, is as follows:
\newcommand*\define[2]{\marginpar{{\setstretch{1}\footnotesize\textbf{{#1}} #2\par}}}

(Credit to lockstep for a critical fix; I adapted the command in its current form from the following thread: Changing the baselineskip in marginpar)
I would like to add a vocabulary list at the end of the document collecting all the words introduced for reference and linking to the first instance in which they occur, to which end I sought to use the glossaries package (in conjunction with hyperref). However, the glossaries package does come with the significant drawback of having to add every glossary entry manually, which, to put it lightly, I regard as a rather daunting prospect for a glossary with hundreds of entries. Since I only want to reproduce the explanations I already provided to begin with, I considered automatically adding entries by embedding them into the command itself, adding a line like so:
\newcommand*\define[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1, description={#2}}
\marginpar{{\setstretch{1}\footnotesize\textbf{\gls{#1}} #2\par}}}

However, this command crashes my document and so isn't working as intended. Is there an alternative way to go about my desired objective with the glossaries package (or with another package unbeknownst to me), or will I have to add all the glossary entries manually?
EDIT: The crash was, in fact, caused by the addition of commas in particular into the definitions in question, which ended up confusing the syntax of the glossary entry (and which I failed to consider); adding another pair of braces around the description did the trick. Thanks to karlh for leading me onto the right track!

The following works for me:
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeglossaries
\newcommand*\define[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1, description=#2}%
  \marginpar{{\setstretch{1}\footnotesize\textbf{\gls{#1}} #2\par}}}

\begin{document}
This is an entry.
\define{entry}{what I entered}%

\printglossaries
\end{document}

If you could post an example that reproduces the error (a "Minimal Working Example," though in this case it would be a "Minimal Crashing Example"), we can help diagnose from there.

welcome! note that it would be better to do it the other way i.e. pull the explanations from a database of entries. if your markup is fairly consistent, you should be able to script the extraction for the most part. I suggest this because defining entries in the document has limitations where glossaries is concerned so you will have less flexibility.

@karlh Thank you for leading me onto the right track! See the updated post for an explanation of what went wrong. I suppose this is a cautionary tale in the importance of conceptualizing minimal working examples, as I genuinely failed to consider something so seemingly obvious.

Without a proper "minimal broken example", as @karlh mentioned, it is difficult to find the root of the problem. In the meantime, I have created an example using the marginnote package. Hope it helps!
The issue likely stems from the fact that the description field in the \newglossaryentry command is missing the curly braces {} around its argument, which could cause a parsing error in your document.
In LaTeX, it's important to enclose each argument in curly braces, especially when you pass multiple arguments to commands. Without the curly braces, LaTeX might not interpret it correctly, leading to crashes or errors.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=2cm, right=5cm,
    top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
    showframe,
    marginpar=4cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}% defines \marginnote for more compatibility, check the manual on ctan: ctan.org/pkg/marginnote
\usepackage{setspace}% defines setstretch command

% order matters: load hyperref first
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\makeglossaries

% "Marginpar on page 1 moved." warning
% \newcommand*\define[2]{
%     \newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1, description=#2}
%     \marginpar{{\setstretch{1}\footnotesize\textbf{\gls{#1}} #2\par}}
% }

\NewDocumentCommand{\define}{mm}{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1}, description={#2}}%
    \marginnote{{\setstretch{1}\footnotesize\textbf{\gls{#1}}: #2\par}}%
}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\define{latex}{Is a markup language specially suited for scientific documents}
\lipsum[1]
\define{maths}{Mathematics is what mathematicians do}[40pt]

\define{formula}{A mathematical expression}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are rendered 
properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

\printglossary

\end{document}



Seems you posted your reply right as I was editing my post to note that the issue has been resolved, haha; thank you for going through all that effort and, in particular, for pointing me to the marginnote package. In any case, I found what was wrong in my attempt to produce a minimal working (or rather crashing) example – see the post for details.
